# Visio automatic container from lines

Tags: excel, containers, visio

I'm using Visio Professional 2016. Is it possible to automatically create containers depending on a column (for example the project name) from external Excel data?

I found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2010/01/12/custom-containers-lists-and-callouts-in-visio-2010/) but I'm not sure if this is want I'm looking for. Besides that it's not easy to follow.

Another question, where can I find settings similar to the properties mapper in yEd? I'd like to create shapes automatically from Excel data. If a new row is added in my external data it is supposed to create a new shape on its own.

Edit: Will [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861526.aspx) using VBA answer all my questions?

Comment: i have the same question.